# How to change keyboard return type when text appears in the textfield

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have a text field whose keyboard return key is `default`.
But I want it to be `UIReturnKeySend` when any text appears on the textfield.
I have tried it as follows.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textFieldshouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
  {
      textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySend;
      return YES;
  }
```

I know I will have to check for some conditions under this method, but for now I want it to at least change the `returnKeyType` which is not working.

As it happens in `autoEnabling` return key (i.e return key becomes active when we enter a text.) I want my return key to change from `default` to `send` whenever text appears.

Comment: Thaks @MDaniyal for the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

`[textField reloadInputViews]` seems to do the trick...

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change it while editing dynamically then write the below code :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textFieldshouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
      textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySend;
      [textField reloadInputViews];
      return YES;
}
```

Comment: actually I had tried this as well. It didn't work either. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the return key type to change when any text appears in the textfield, why don't you try this :

```
  - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
     if([textField.text length] > 0){
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySend;
      }
     else{
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually changing the return key under this method will not give the result I want.